# Functions of setMaxDate(new Date(today)) in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative functions to set the max date ?

```
var today = new Date();
Text.setMaxDate(new Date(today));
```

The above function goes in error when executed in ie11 and working in chrome

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it does nt execute after that line.

Comment: Can you provide exact error in IE 11 browser. This function to use set date in calendar. Kindly provide some more example where to use this code.